# How do I change the color of <tr> when I clicked the <td> inside of it that already have a onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to change the `<tr>` color when I click the `<td>` inside of it and remove the color when I click on another `<td>` in the same table (I have multiple tables) ? The problem is I already have a onclick function that I need.

here is my html:

```
<table class="table table-sm mb-0">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">Plant</th>
   <th scope="col">Location</th>
   <th scope="col" class="text-center">Total Pallet</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="rows">
 </tbody>
</table>
```

here is my JS:

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
 html += "<tr>"
  + "<td>" + value["plant_name"] + "</td>"
  + "<td>" + value["loc_name"] + "</td>"
  + "<td class='pointer text-center' onclick='getModelData(\"" + value["werks"] + "\", \"" + value["lgort"] + "\")'><u>" + value["total"] + "<u></td>"
  + "</tr>";
});

$("#rows").html(html);
```

I have tried adding another function inside the onclick but there is no result

```
function getOtherData() {
  var row = $(this);

  row.css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

Comment: If you don't show us _what_ you actually tried, we can't tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Simple answer: stop using `onclick=` and use event binding.  Start here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/   you'll need to use *event delegation* which is mentioned on that page and detailed here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: I have an example for your reference:

https://jsfiddle.net/xtwcpg19/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to set the parent `tr` of the clicked element to have a red background the event handler you bind must be able to get a reference to that element. Using `onX` attributes do not get this out of the box - you need to pass the element as an argument manually. This is part of the reason they are not good practice and should be avoided.

Also note that there are several other things you can do to improve the quality of your code, such as using `map()` and a template literal to build your HTML which should be appended to the table, using CSS to style the UI instead of the `<u>` element, using classes to dynamically update the UI instead of explicitly setting `style` on the element itself and finally adding unobtrusive event handlers.

Here's a working example with all the above amendments made. Note the use of `data` attributes instead of passing arguments in the `onclick` attribute.

```js
const data = [
  { plant_name: "plant_name 1", loc_name: "loc_name 1", lgort: "lgort 1", werks: "werks 1", total: "total 1" },
  { plant_name: "plant_name 2", loc_name: "loc_name 2", lgort: "lgort 2", werks: "werks 2", total: "total 2" },
  { plant_name: "plant_name 3", loc_name: "loc_name 3", lgort: "lgort 3", werks: "werks 3", total: "total 3" },
  { plant_name: "plant_name 4", loc_name: "loc_name 4", lgort: "lgort 4", werks: "werks 4", total: "total 4" }
]

let html = data.map(obj => `
  <tr>
    <td>${obj.plant_name}</td>
    <td>${obj.loc_name}</td>
    <td class="pointer text-center" data-werks="${obj.werks}" data-lgort="${obj.lgort}" data-total="${obj.total}">${obj.total}</td>
  </tr>`);

$("#rows").html(html);

$('td.pointer').on('click', e => {
  const $td = $(e.target);
  const $tr = $td.closest('tr');
  $('.highlight').not($tr).removeClass('highlight');
  $tr.toggleClass('highlight');
  
  // read model data:
  console.log($td.data('werks'));
  console.log($td.data('lgort'));
  console.log($td.data('total'));
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
} 

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

td.pointer {
  text-decoration: underline;
} 

tr.highlight {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-sm mb-0">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">Plant</th>
   <th scope="col">Location</th>
   <th scope="col" class="text-center">Total Pallet</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="rows">
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this solution and it is working beautifully

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Simply bind another click event on your `td` and remove all background before adding new background to clicked item. See the following example.

```js
var data = [
    { "plant_name": "Plant 1", "loc_name": "Loc 1", "total": "10", "werks": "1" },
    { "plant_name": "Plant 2", "loc_name": "Loc 2", "total": "10", "werks": "2" },
    { "plant_name": "Plant 3", "loc_name": "Loc 3", "total": "10", "werks": "3" },
    { "plant_name": "Plant 4", "loc_name": "Loc 4", "total": "10", "werks": "4" },
    { "plant_name": "Plant 5", "loc_name": "Loc 5", "total": "10", "werks": "5" }
];

var html = "";
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  html += "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + value["plant_name"] + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + value["loc_name"] + "</td>" +
    "<td class='pointer text-center' onclick='getModelData(\"" + value["werks"] + "\", \"" + value["lgort"] + "\")'><u>" + value["total"] + "<u></td>" +
    "</tr>";
});

$("#rows").html(html);

$("td").off("click").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("tbody").find("tr").css('background-color', '')
  getOtherData($(this).closest("tr"));
});

function getOtherData(target) {
  target.css('background-color', 'red');
}

function getModelData(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-sm mb-0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Plant</th>
      <th scope="col">Location</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">Total Pallet</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="rows">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend event delegation over `.off().on()` as .off will remove all click events, losing the benefit of using event binding and OPs original request (essentially: run two, separate, click handlers)